# Why i am not able to delete the files(PHP)?

Tags: php

I use a form where i have listed the data from database like title, date etc. from the database and using checkboxes i use the multiple delete operation

For example my code look like this

```
<form method="post" action="action.php">
<input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"/>
<input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete"/>
```

and in the action.php the code is like this

```
 $checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];
    //count the number of selected checkboxes in an array
    $count = count($checkbox);
    //Create a for loop to delete 
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)   {
    $del_id = $checkbox[$i];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM news WHERE id='$del_id'";
    $result_delete_data = mysql_query($sql);
    }
```

Now the table i want to delete actually have 5 table entities like title, timestamp,pic_title,pic_brief,pic_detail the last three entities i.e pic_title, pic_brief and pic_detail is actually storing the path of the image for example the value stored in one of the 3 entity would look like this `upload/file/pic_title1.jpg`

My problem is when i run my first for loop it successfully deletes the table without any problem but the file which exist in the file directory remains intact. i want to delete that file too, to remove that file i thought of adding another for loop which i did something like this

```
for($j=0;$j<$count;$j++){
        $delete_id = $checkbox[$j];
        $query = "SELECT news.pic_title, news.pic_brief, news.pic_detail FROM news WHERE id = '$delete_id'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        unlink($row['pic_title']);
        unlink($row['pic_brief']);
        unlink($row['pic_detail']);
        }
```

The above code is unable to delete the requested file, my Query string is perfectly working fine i tested it by removing the unlink function and printing the values, it prints all the selected value , but it is refusing to delete the file and when i try to run the loop it shows error in the last three line, while i am pretty sure that, $row['pic_title'], $row['pic_brief'], $row['pic_brief'], have the full path of the image.

```
    unlink($row['pic_title']);
    unlink($row['pic_brief']);
    unlink($row['pic_brief']);
```

where i am going wrong?

P.S: There is nothing wrong with file permission because when i individually try to run the function unlink it deletes the file from the same directory.

EDIT : This is the error message i get

```
Warning: unlink() [function.unlink]: No error in C:\wamp\www\bn\admin-login\action.php on line 580

Warning: unlink() [function.unlink]: No error in C:\wamp\www\bn\admin-login\action.php on line 581

Warning: unlink() [function.unlink]: No error in C:\wamp\www\bn\admin-login\action.php on line 582
```

To be more precise i tested this function individually in php and it is working perfectly fine

```
$target = 'upload/file/file1.jpg';
unlink($target);
```

and for this reason i dont think the file permission is causing the error, i guess i am going wrong somewhere with the logic.

@Lekensteyn got me the solution, thank you  Lekensteyn.

actually i had to first hold the value in a variable and then unlink the file. the working code looks like this.

```
 for($j=0;$j<$count;$j++){
        $delete_id = $checkbox[$j];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE id = '$delete_id'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $pic_title = $row['pic_title'];
        $pic_brief = $row['pic_brief'];
        $pic_detail = $row['pic_detail'];
        unlink($pic_title);
        unlink($pic_brief);
        unlink($pic_detail);
        }
```

Comment: Wow... 'no error'? You're right, no file permissions on windows.

Comment: I have edited and posted the error message please have a look.

Comment: Is it an accident that in last code snippet you are deleting the same file twice?

Comment: @Lekensteyn , i am not getting you. what is causing that error. you mean to say it is because of the file permission? to be more precise i tested the unlink permission individually and tried deleting the same file from the same directory and it is working.

Comment: @spbfox No that is not happening either as i told you i want to delete all the three files which value exist in the database.. that is why it is showing that three errors.

Comment: I'm currently looking in the [PHP source code](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/branches/PHP_5_3/ext/standard/file.c?revision=302386&view=markup#l1538) for 'No error'. So instead of `unlink($file)`, did you do `echo $file`, and unlink it afterwards? 
What PHP version are you using?

Comment: @Lekensteyn You got the solution for me that trick works, i am able to delete it now successfully thank you..

Comment: can you please apply fileperms($filename) and tell us what are the file permssions

Comment: @Ayaz doesnt serve the purpose now, i solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be file permissions. You need to be the owner of the file in order to delete it.

Some hosters run the website under the user 'apache' (or similar), but the files are owned by the ftpuser (accountxxxx for example).

Check the current working dir too, with `echo getcwd()` if the paths not absolute.

Your script is vulnerable to SQL injection too, a post request with `checkbox[]='||1||'` deletes everything.

Comment: Just to add a small detail: in addition to file you need to have write permissions to directory entry itself. In other words, to delete /var/www/html/foo.php you need to have a write permission in /var/www/html too.

Comment: Please read the post properly , i said i tested the function individually and it is working, i am able to delete the file hence there is no question of going wrong with file permission. and i have still not hosted the file i am testing it in my desktop powered by windows.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

at the top of your script.
Your problem is program flow related and can be found only by using *debugging.*
Start from displaying ALL errors occurred and repair them. This will most likely lead you to the reason you could not delete your files.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your path to upload is the problem. In your test script:

```
$target = 'upload/file/file1.jpg';
unlink($target);
```

I bet you ran that from a directory right below 'upload/' right?

And this delete script, it's probably not in the same directory?

I recommend using the full path to the 'upload/file/' directory; this will vary depending on your configuration, but probably looks like /www/htdocs/upload/file or /var/www/public_html/upload/file.

To make the script more transportable, you can use the PHP constant **FILE** to figure out the directory.  I usually set this app/site wide in a bootstrap or universal configuration file, along the lines of

```
define('PATH', dirname(__FILE__)); # sets PATH with the directory name of the bootstrap file where this code lives
```

I sometimes key on something in my path I can rely on, say my app name.  Say my bootstrap is here:

```
/www/apps/golf-scorecard/bootstrap.php
```

I might split on 'golf-scorecard'.

```
list($path,) = explode('golf-scorecard',dirname(__FILE__)); # $path should be /www/apps/
define('PATH', $path.'golf-scorecard'); # since I split on it, I have to add it back in
```

This means if I move the app/site to another server, or clone it from a repository onto a machine where the document root is, say `/home/username/apps/golf-scorecard/htdocs/`, then it won't matter.  It does couple the app name but I am okay with that.

Comment: you are absolutely wrong on this, i havent structured my code for now hence it all lies in a single directory only the upload folder is different, i would have appreciated if you have gone though the post correctly i have already solved the problem . the unlink() does not accept direct path so first it has to be a variable that would hold the path, and this was causing me error, when i tried holding the value in variable first it worked for me at first instance.

Answer (score 0):

first thing is you need to check the file permissions .you need to give `777` permission to the folder.and then  follow below code

```
$target = 'upload/file/file1.jpg';
unlink($target);
```